# SSH remote forwarding: require authentication to both the forwarding server and target server

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, port-forwarding

I want to use SSH remote forwarding through a server I own to connect to a company computer (the "target" server), by running something like this on the target:

```
ssh -R '*:10000:localhost:22' forwarding-server
```

The problem is that the target isn't always kept up-to-date, and I have no control over this. I don't want to make its SSH server directly accessible from the Internet.

Ideally, I would like to require authentication *to the forwarding server*, with an SSH key, before it allows forwarding to the target server. When I set this up on a test machine, the connection was forwarded immediately to the target server instead.

Is there a way to require authentication *before* the connection is forwarded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to require authentication before the connection is forwarded?

That's actually how SSH always works – unless the forwarding server's administrator deliberately went and *disabled* authentication for some reason.

Run the command with `-v -v` options added. You will see one of these possibilities:

1. you're being automatically authenticated using your SSH public-key;
2. you're being automatically authenticated using GSSAPI (Kerberos);
3. you're reusing a multiplexed connection (ControlMaster/ControlPath), i.e. just adding a new tunnel to an already authenticated session;
4. all authentication mechanisms are skipped because the remote account has a blank password and the server was configured to allow this.